# Using MFC in a "managed C++" application

Tags: mfc, c++-cli, managed-c++

One of our products is a C++ application - using MFC (MDI). (And we skin the application with Codejock.)

I've been asked if we could "port the application to .NET" - so it would be possible to use, e.g., C# libraries and other .NET features. I know there is something called "C++.NET" - or maybe (if I understand it right) it should be called "managed C++" now. But I don't know much about it.

My question: Is this at all possible? Could we run an MFC-application as "managed C++"? (And can an application using Codejock be run as a "managed C++" application?) There is some other threads about this, but I haven't been able to find "a definitive answer"...

I'd be very grateful for some good advice! :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can managed and unmanaged C++/MFC be mixed in one dll?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018944/can-managed-and-unmanaged-c-mfc-be-mixed-in-one-dll)

Comment: I think the [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018944/can-managed-and-unmanaged-c-mfc-be-mixed-in-one-dll) is a good start but **it is not a duplicate**, because over there he has no MFC GUI, and you are clearly asking how to integrate .NET stuff into a MFC GUI application. *Are* you asking that?

Comment: Maybe you should reconsider renaming the title to "Using .NET libraries from a MFC/Codejock application"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to keep your MFC/Codejock GUI and allow the use of .NET libraries from you application's C++ code.

This is indeed possible, but for a complete application that is currently compiled as "native" C++ it is probably not such a good idea to convert all of it to being compiled with [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI). "[It Just Works (IJW)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173185.aspx)" is a nice meme, but it doesn't work always :-)

We have the same situation, namely a C++/MFC/Codejock application that needs to call into .NET assemblies. This works mostly without problems:

- We have C++/CLI modules that offer a native C++ DLL interface for the native C++ code to call into and that then route these call on to an assembly written in C#.
- We also have C++/CLI assemblies that offer a .NET interface for the C# code and then call back into pure native modules.

It should also be possible to have a single (say, `exe`) project that is compiled natively and you only enable the `/clr` switch for selected `cpp` files that need managed interop. And at the end you link everything together. Since we've never mixed it *that way*, I can't really say anything about this approach however. What I can say *for sure* though is that it *is* possible to compile parts on a module as `/clr` and parts as native.

Comment: I can confirm this, we have a large MFC application with only specific sources using managed code, only these sources are marked with `/clr`

Comment: Thanks for great information! :-) Well, the "need for .NET" from management is a bit vaugue... One reason for looking into this is, as you say, to be able to use .NET libraries. And as I can see from the links, this wouldn't be a problem. But they have other things on their wish list: (1) To use .NET GUI components. (There are more to choose from in .NET.) (2) They are considering replacing MFC/Codejock with .NET altogether. (We have another application running .NET, and they think it would be nice to have only one enviroment to maintain on customer computers.) Your ...

Comment: ... opinion on that? Is (1) at all possible - will .NET GUI components (Microsoft or third party) run in the MFC framework? And (2) would require a major rewrite. (Or am I wrong?) It sounds to me that there wouldn't be much reason to do this in C++/CLI; better to do a complete port to C#.

Comment: Yes, you can use .NET GUI components in a MFC appliaction. Mixing them is non-trivial as far as I know (we do it somewhere, but not in the area of our code I am knowledgeable).

Comment: "replacing MFC/Codejock with .NET altogether" - this is essentially a full re-write of the GUI part of your app. Can't imagine anyone making a business case of that unless for very small apps. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem some years ago, and found that unless for trivial cases converting from un-managed to managed or reverse side was really painfull. I ended leaving the two worlds each in its side, and simply use interop to have the COM - .NET compatibility.

It was not very nice, but a lot cheaper. The conclusion that we should wait a major evolution to consider a full rewriting.

Comment: Writing C++/CLI interop assemblies is fairly painless, and almost trivial. It allows you to provide a managed interface to native code and vice versa. Writing a separate interop assembly for either direction is recommended, but you can have a single assembly just as well. Mixed mode assemblies have both native and managed exports that applications can link to.